# Code Issue on implementing Inference in Frames with Prolog

Tags: prolog

This is a code sample took from Ivan Bratko's book "Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence - 3rd edition - pg 377". It works perfectly for the query `?-value(kiwi, active_at, night)`. by giving the result as `true`.

But it also gives the result as `true` for the query `?- value(kiwi, active_at, daylight).` and it should be `false`.

How should I modify it, or am I missing something?

```
%--------Define frames
bird(a_kind_of, animal).
bird(active_at, daylight).

albatross(a_kind_of, bird).
albatross(colour, black).
albatross(size, 10).

kiwi(a_kind_of, bird).
kiwi(active_at, night).
kiwi(colour, brown).
kiwi(size, 24).

albert(instance_of, albatross).
albert(size, 10).

%--------Inference in Frames
value(Frame, Slot, Value):-
    Query =.. [Frame, Slot, Value],
    call(Query), !.     %Value is directly retrieved
value(Frame, Slot, Value):-
    parent(Frame, ParentName),
    value(ParentName, Slot, Value).     % More general rule

parent(Frame, ParentName):-
    (Query =.. [Frame, a_kind_of, ParentName];
    Query =.. [Frame, instance_of, ParentName]),
    call(Query).
```

Comment: It gives correct result, why should it give it false?

Comment: Replace: `Query =.. [Frame, Slot, Value],
    call(Query)` by `call(Frame, Slot, Value)`! It worx, guaranteed!

Answer (score 3):

First let's take a look at the queries in question. Your first query...

```
?- value(kiwi, active_at, night).
true.
```

... succeeds with the first rule of value/3. You can see that if you try the goals manually. The query...

```
?- Query =.. [kiwi, active_at, night].
```

... succeeds and unifies the variable `Query` with `kiwi(active_at, night)`:

```
?- Query =.. [kiwi, active_at, night].
Query = kiwi(active_at, night).
```

The next goal calls `Query`...

```
?- call(kiwi(active_at, night)).
true.
```

... and succeeds since you have a fact `kiwi(active_at, night).`. The next goal `!` prevents Prolog from backtracking and searching for further solutions therefore the query `?- value(kiwi, active_at, night).` succeeds deterministically (you don't have to press `;` after the first solution). Now let's take a look at your second query...

```
?- value(kiwi, active_at, daylight).
true ;
false.
```

... that succeeds as well. The first rule of value/3 unifies `Query` with `kiwi(active_at, daylight)` and subsequently calls it:

```
?- call(kiwi(active_at, daylight)).
false.
```

This call fails since you don't have a suitable fact. Note that at this point the rule can't succeed, so Prolog doesn't bother with the last goal and moves on to the second rule of value/3. Here the first goal

```
?- parent(kiwi,ParentName).
ParentName = bird ;
false.
```

... succeeds and is unifying `ParentName` with `bird` due to the first argument of the disjunction...

```
?- Query =.. [kiwi, a_kind_of, ParentName].
Query = kiwi(a_kind_of, ParentName).
```

... and the subsequent call/1 in parent/2:

```
?- call(kiwi(a_kind_of, ParentName)).
ParentName = bird.
```

Now the second goal of the second rule of value/3 calls itself, starting with the first rule again:

```
?- value(bird, active_at, daylight).
true.
```

This succeeds and therefore the query...

```
?- value(kiwi, active_at, daylight).
true
```

... succeeds as well. Note that Prolog is waiting for input after answering `true` and if you press `;` it is searching for further solutions:

```
?- value(kiwi, active_at, daylight).
true ;
```

Although the goal `value(bird, active_at, daylight)` succeeded deterministically due to the cut in the first rule of value/3, the first goal (`parent(kiwi,ParentName)`) of the calling predicate (the second rule of value/3) left a choice point open (see the query above) and now Prolog is backtracking there to search for other solutions. But there are none so Prolog answers:

```
?- value(kiwi, active_at, daylight).
true ;
false.
```

However, if you ask at what time kiwis are active Prolog will answer:

```
?- value(kiwi, active_at, X).
X = night.
```

The reason why `daylight` is not derived here is again the cut. After the first rule of value/3 succeeds for `X = night` it prevents Prolog from searching for other solutions. From a logical point of view this behaviour is outright incorrect: Either kiwis are active at day and night, then the last query should yield both solutions, or they are nocturnal, then the query `?- value(kiwi, active_at, daylight).` should fail. I don't want to speculate on the intended behaviour of the predicate value/3, so I will refer to the [Wikipedia entry on kiwi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiwi) instead which states: *Kiwi are shy and usually nocturnal. Their mostly nocturnal habits may be a result of habitat intrusion by predators, including humans. In areas of New Zealand where introduced predators have been removed, such as sanctuaries, kiwi are often seen in daylight.*

If you want to have both solutions I would suggest to add some facts iscallable/1 (don't call it callable/1 though, since there's already a built-in with that name) that cover your facts, add it in value/3 and parent/2 and remove the cut like so:

```
iscallable(bird).                                 % <- new fact
iscallable(albatross).                            % <- new fact
iscallable(kiwi).                                 % <- new fact
iscallable(albert).                               % <- new fact

value(Frame, Slot, Value):-
    iscallable(Frame),                            % <- new goal iscallable/1
    Query =.. [Frame, Slot, Value],
    call(Query).                                  % <- removed cut here
value(Frame, Slot, Value):-
    parent(Frame, ParentName),
    value(ParentName, Slot, Value).

parent(Frame, ParentName):-
    iscallable(Frame),                            % <- new goal iscallable/1
    (Query =.. [Frame, a_kind_of, ParentName];
     Query =.. [Frame, instance_of, ParentName]),
    call(Query).
```

With these alterations you'll consistently get both solutions:

```
?- value(kiwi, active_at,X).
X = night ;
X = daylight ;
false.

?- value(kiwi, active_at,night).
true ;
false.

?- value(kiwi, active_at,daylight).
true ;
false.
```

To see why you need something like iscallable/1 in rule 1 of value/3, remove it and consider the following query:

```
?- value(kiwi, active_at, X).
X = night ;
X = daylight ;
ERROR: value/3: Undefined procedure: animal/2
   Exception: (9) animal(active_at, _G4462) ? creep
   Exception: (8) value(animal, active_at, _G4462) ? creep
```

The predicate value/3 is trying to call a predicate animal/2 that does not exist. To see why you need something like iscallable/1 in parent/2, remove it and consider the following query:

```
?- value(kiwi, active_at,X).
X = night ;
X = daylight ;
ERROR: parent/2: Undefined procedure: animal/2
   Exception: (10) animal(a_kind_of, _G4558) ? creep
```

On the other hand, if you opt for the night solution only, you can define a fact nocturnalbird/2 that describes activity at night time and alter the facts kiwi/2 accordingly:

```
nocturnalbird(active_at, night).  % <- new fact

%kiwi(a_kind_of, bird).           % <- remove fact
kiwi(a_kind_of, nocturnalbird).   % <- new fact
%kiwi(active_at, night).          % <- remove fact
kiwi(colour, brown).
kiwi(size, 24).
```

This yields the desired results:

```
?- value(kiwi, active_at,X).
X = night ;
false.

?- value(kiwi, active_at,night).
true ;
false.

?- value(kiwi, active_at,daylight).
false.
```

If you plan to extend this example to include animal properties for nocturnal birds as well, you'll need to add a fact `nocturnalbird(a_kind_of, animal).` as well as include iscallable/1 in value/3 and parent/2 like above.

### EDIT:

In fact, you don't need =../2 here at all, as pointed out by @false in the comments. You can simply use call/N instead:

```
value(Frame, Slot, Value):-
    iscallable(Frame),               
    call(Frame, Slot, Value).                    % <- here
value(Frame, Slot, Value):-
    parent(Frame, ParentName),
    value(ParentName, Slot, Value).

parent(Frame, ParentName):-
    iscallable(Frame),
    (call(Frame, a_kind_of, ParentName);         % <- here
     call(Frame, instance_of, ParentName)).      % <- here
```

Comment: What about `call/N`? These `(=..)/2`s are so malaprop.

Comment: @false: Thanks for the hint. I was so busy trying to stay close to the original code that I completely overlooked the obvious :-D. I updated my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this very late, but another way of handling this is to change the first clause of ***value*** to:

```
value(Frame, Slot, Value):-
    call(Frame, Slot, V), !,    % Value is directly retrieved
    V = Value.                  % Slot might already inherit value so check
```